# Protecting against sudo inside shell-scripts, makefiles, etc

Tags: linux, unix, sudo

Usually, when I run `sudo`, it will ask me to enter a password the first time and it will remember that I'm authenticated for the next few minutes, until that authentication times out.

This leaves a hole in the system's security. Coupled with a bit of social engineering, a malicious shell-script/Makefile/etc. could run `sudo` inside it and gain access to root.

Without giving up the convenience of the "remember authentication" feature, I would still like to have a more secure setup. Is there a way to set up `sudo` to only remember authentication for the *pid* that authenticated successfully, or something similar? I know that you can configure `sudo` to ask for authentication every time, but I'm thinking of something that doesn't forgo the convenience for the security.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `sudo -K` before running anything you don’t trust.

Answer (score 0):

The closest you could come to this would be to rename the **sudo** command to a name that the attackers do not know.  Yes, this is [security by obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_by_obscurity), but if you can invoke **sudo** then a script running as you can invoke it (if it knows its name).